# How to adjust the size of a table to the current page?

Tags: tables

How could I adjust the size of the following table to the size of the current page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
 \hline
 \textit{«~essayer d’éveiller chez eux~»}& (l.~8)\\
 \hline
 \textit{«~essayer de les / de les emmener en vacances~»} &(l.~9)\\
 \hline
\textit{«~les faire traverser un paysage~»} &(l.~25)\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{}
\end{center}\\
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by adjusting the size of the table. Do you want to extend the columns to fill the text width? In which ratio? The `tabularx` page offers flexible columns. Btw., remove `\\ ` after `\end{center}`.  Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}\end{center}`, this avoids unnecessary space. Why do you use the `table` enviroment, if you want the table in a fixed place (`[h!]`)? If it is just because of being able to add a caption, use the `capt-of` or the `\caption` package.

Comment: @gernot : yes, I'd like to extend the columns to fill the text width. The ratio is indicated in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tabular*`, `tabularx` and `tabulary`  to set the width or the maximum width of the table. Each option have their own  particularities. I suggest learn the three. See the examples below.

If you what a width equal to the text width, `\linewidth` could be the safest setting in most situations. Obviously, you can avoid `\centering` when the table have really have width equal to linewidth.

For comparison, I cannot resist suppress the vertical lines and use the `booktabs` rules in some table (of course, you can use this style in the other tables as well). Also I left a table without forcing the maximum width. What look better?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,xcolor}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,showframe]{geometry}

%to show just the left/right margins
\makeatletter 
\def\Gm@hrule{}%
\def\Gm@vrule{\color{red!20}\vrule width 1pt height\textheight}%
\def\Gm@hruled{}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|r|}\hline
 \textit{«~essayer d’éveiller chez eux~»}& (l.~8)\\ \hline
 \textit{«~essayer de les / de les emmener en vacances~»} &(l.~9)\\\hline
\textit{«~les faire traverser un paysage~»} &(l.~25)\\\hline
 \end{tabular*}
 \caption{A \texttt{tabular*} table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|r|}\hline
 \textit{«~essayer d’éveiller chez eux~»}& (l.~8)\\ \hline
 \textit{«~essayer de les / de les emmener en vacances~»} &(l.~9)\\\hline
\textit{«~les faire traverser un paysage~»} &(l.~25)\\\hline
 \end{tabularx}
 \caption{A \texttt{tabularx} table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|@{\hspace{3em}}L|@{\hspace{2em}}r@{\hspace{3em}}|}\toprule
 \textit{«~essayer d’éveiller chez eux~»}& (l.~8)\\\midrule
 \textit{«~essayer de les / de les emmener en vacances~»} &(l.~9)\\\midrule
\textit{«~les faire traverser un paysage~»} &(l.~25)\\\bottomrule
 \end{tabulary}
  \caption{A \texttt{tabulary} table}

\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L@{\qquad}R}\toprule
 \textit{«~essayer d’éveiller chez eux~»}& (l.~8)\\
 \textit{«~essayer de les / de les emmener en vacances~»} &(l.~9)\\
\textit{«~les faire traverser un paysage~»} &(l.~25)\\\bottomrule
 \end{tabulary}
  \caption{A \texttt{tabulary} non forced table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In general, a `tabular*`-based solution looks awful if there are interior vertical columns. That said, the `tabularx`-based solution doesn't look a lot better than the `tabular*` solution if interior vertical bars are used. I'd omit the interior vertical bars in both cases.

Comment: @Mico  I started with the style of the question to focus in the main problem (the width of the table) but ended with one table without vertical rules just to show graphically what you explain. One can identify faster the good, the bad and the ugly when you when facing the three gunmen together. `;)`. Of course, I prefer the table 4. I never ever use vertical rules in any serious work.